# When should I put a semicolon after a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My examples:

(First example **area** is the function assignment with semicolon)

```
function makeImage() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("tshirtCanvas");
**canvas.onclick = function () {
    window.location = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};**
}
```

vs

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("previewButton");
    button.onclick = previewHandler;


    makeImage();
}
```

I thought I had the hang of when to use it, and when not to, but I guess I do not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should put a semi-colon after a function when you use it as a value:

```
 var fn = function () {};
 blarg.fn = function () {};
 doStuffWith(function () {});
```

If you're just declaring a named function by itself, you don't need the semicolon:

```
function doFoo() {}
```

Note that in the top cases, you don't always *have* to have a semicolon, but you should put one anyway.

Comment: I understand, but in my case, isn't the window.onload = function()...  giving the onload event a value? So why would it not have a semicolon?

Comment: Remember that JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion--in certain cases, you do not *have* to have a semicolon. However, you should probably include a semicolon anyhow because the rules are complicated and making mistakes is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Function expressions get semicolons (normal line ending rules apply). Function declarations do not.

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration doesn't need it after. Just if you are calling it.

```
function doThis(args){
getterMethod(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning a function to a *property*, you should put a semicolon.
So you could put a semicolon for the window.onload because you are assigning a function to the onload property of the window. The semicolon isn't required, but I highly recommended you put it to prevent confusion.

```
window.onload = function() {
    init();
    doSomethingElse();
};
```

From the [MDN Docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)